# Is it possible to resemble all queries using codeigniter active records

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

For those who are familiar with code-igniter active records, I want to ask them a suggestive question..

Is it possible to denote all types of mysql queries by code-igniter active records?

For example i have this query, can it be converted into some active records fashion

```
SELECT *
FROM td_job j join
     td_skill s
     on find_in_set(s.skill_id, j.job_skill) > 0 and
        s.skill_slug LIKE '%$job_param%';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No they can't although there are workaround, so maybe that means they 'technically' can be?

What I mean is as queries get more complicated you end up writing parts of the queries yourself while not actually using the active record.

For example, in the **join** statement:

```
$this->db
    ->from('td_job as j')
    ->join('td_skill as s', 'find_in_set(s.skill_id, j.job_skill) > 0 and s.skill_slug LIKE \'%$job_param%\'');
```

^this query should work *(though you may have to alter the tags a bit since I didn't test it).*

However it essentially makes active record not very useful since you ended up writing the 'raw' query for the 'on' part of join since there is no proper way to translate that to active records.